# Connection issue via Delphi and OLEDB to IBM Netezza

Tags: delphi, oledb, ado, netezza

**Task:** connect to IBM Netezza and get Recordset.

I have a next code in Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LADOQuery: TADOQuery;
  LRecordSet: _Recordset;
  LRecCount : Integer;
begin
  LADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    LADOQuery.Prepared := True;
    LADOQuery.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=NZOLEDB;Password=password;User ID=admin;Data Source=10.25.11.103;Initial Catalog=test;' +
      'Persist Security Info=True;Port=5480;Logging Level=1;';
//    LADOQuery.ConnectionString :=
//      'Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=10.25.11.103;port=5480;database=test;username=admin;password=password;';
    LADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select * from table_1;';
    LADOQuery.Open; { !------- Error under OLEDB -------! }
    LRecordSet := LADOQuery.Recordset;
    if Assigned(LRecordSet) and (LRecordSet.State = adStateOpen) then
    begin
      LRecCount := LRecordSet.RecordCount;
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(LRecCount));
    end;
    LADOQuery.Close;
  finally
    FreeAndNIl(LADOQuery);
  end;
end;
```

There are already drivers for Netezza DB in my system:

- OLEDB(32x and 64x versions) - Product version 7.0.0.4
- ODBC (32x and 64x versions) - Product version 7.0.0.4

When I try use connection settings under OLEDB (NZOLEDB) I get "EOleException error..." otherwise while I use settings uder ODBC (NetezzaSQL) I successfull connect and get correct result.

**Question:** What can it be reason of error under OLEDB Delphi XE (also tried under XE4)?

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Test.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Unspecified error'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

PS. Intersting fact: I can connect to Netezza DB and get result via OLEDB driver with same connection string under .NET program:

```
String sConnectionString = "Provider=NZOLEDB;Password=password;User ID=admin;Data Source=10.25.11.103;Initial Catalog=test;"; 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection nzconn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand nzcomm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the AV happens on .Open procedure?

Comment: Yes, it is happens on .Open procedure

Comment: try with a separate TADOConnection and assign it to your TADOQuery...

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but still getting the same error as previous without separate ADOConection

Comment: can you post the **exact** error you are receiving? Please also state the version of your netazza driver...

Comment: I have just updated description of this issue